# Generate dyamic 'week of' date range

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails

I was in need of a method to dynamically generate a week range, so that the view reads something like "Week of May 16 - 22" and updates automatically. Here's the helper method I came up with, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to have gone about this.

#### Dashboards Helper:

```
def week_range
  today = DateTime.now
  week_start = today.beginning_of_week(:monday).strftime("%B %d")
  week_end = today.end_of_week(:monday).strftime("%d")
  "#{week_start} - #{week_end}"
end
```

#### Dashboards View:

```
<h1>Week of <%= week_range %></h1>
```

#### Output:

Week of May 16 - 22

Comment: Is `May 30 - 05` valid, or should it be `May 30 - Jun 05`?

Comment: Oh good point @tokland. The way it works now it wouldn't take into account weeks that span multiple months. I guess a change would make would be to conditionally show the month in the second date if it doesn't match the first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good. Just a couple of details:

- Instead of hardcoding `DateTime.now` within the method, add an optional argument. Easier to test and more versatile to use.
- The month leap is not considered.

I'd write:

```
def week_range(date: DateTime.now, start_day: :monday)
  start_date = date.beginning_of_week(start_day)
  end_date = date.end_of_week(start_day)
  start_date_string = start_date.strftime("%B %d")
  week_end_string = (start_date.month == end_date.month) ? 
    end_date.strftime("%d") : end_date.strftime("%B %d")  
  "#{start_date_string} - #{week_end_string}"
end
```